# Proper setup of multi doman site

Tags: multisite

I have a "family" of sites that I have neglected over time but am about to put a major effort into.  I would like to rebuild, restructure and go.  Here is what I have:

allnaturalgoodness.com - talks about all natural remedies and products

wingandtailfarm.com - talks about my farming operations and different farming related items that tie together with allnaturalgoodness.com

coveredbridgeproductions.com - I was doing videography work but am not any longer

dogriveroutdoors.com - this was an amazon affiliate site with outdoor products

now what I am looking to do is create a blog.  XYZ.COM (as an example) .  Currently I am a self-employed, a farmer, RVer, and looking for residual income.

My question is, do I build each individual site, or can I somehow build the blog and include everything?  Can I redirect something like wingandtailfarm, allnaturalgoodness, dogriveroutdoors to a category on my blog?  what is the best plan?

should I get rid of all the domains and copy the content I already have to my blog?

Just not sure what the best plan would be.  I think it would be more simple if I were managing 1 site and posting info to various categories as opposed to managing multiple sites.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest only combining topics that are somewhat related. For example, your natural remedies and farming might go together, depending on what kind of articles you write. Videography and outdoor Amazon stuff seem like they are totally separate topics.

You might be able to set up a MultiSite and [map the external domains](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-a-wordpress-multisite-network-with-multiple-domains/). It's a bit tricky to set up but once you get the setup done it would be a single place to update everything.

Personally, I would keep either the natural domain or the farming domain and combine those two into one site - 301 redirect whichever one you don't keep - and then I'd keep separate domains for video and affiliate. If MultiSite domain mapping is too big of a headache just keep 3 separate WP installs.

Comment: Ok thanks. Im goingvto ditch the video site all together. I think  I would like to make a blog XYZ.com.  And that be the main site.  Somehow I have everything else incorporated into it.  XYZ is where I talk about rv traveling, camping, homeschool, outdoor activities, cool products, farms i visit, and offer my services. I dont know that multi site thing. Is there a link you can share? I could use all the help i can get.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Should i just take the content i have, paste it to the new blog in a category that reflects the content like farm, then redirect the domans to a relevant page on the xyz blog?  I am willing to do whatever makes the most sense from an admin perspective and seo perspective. What are the benefits either way?  Can the multisites be themed differently? I guess i need to read more

Comment: Yes to all. Copy your old content over (it will help your SEO if you also tweak it here and there so it's updated/refreshed) onto the new site. Multisite's main benefit is you update all the code together - a single core update will take care of all the sites; single plugin or theme update updates all as well. Yes, you can activate different plugins and themes on all of the subsites, so they appear to be completely independent sites but they're easier to manage as one. Downside is if it gets hacked it can more easily affect all the subsites at once.

Comment: Ok so i see i "could" do a bunch of things. If you can tell me what i should do, or draw a diagram for me or a something. :) im understanding but not fully grasping it i think. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Personally I'd set up a Multisite. It'll take a little research but I think you'll find it easier to manage all the updates and code in one place. They're not that hard to set up and get used to.

Comment: Ok so if i do the multisite i will basically have multiple sites in one management location. I will post content to each separate site from one central location. Is that correct?  I think what i would rather have 1 site with all the content in one place maybe just using the various domains to point to a location. That way i am not playing with multiple themes and multiple places etc. is this a bad idea?  If the multisite is the way to go then so be it.

Comment: OK you have me sold on the multi site.   Is the only way to do it buying a subscription somewhere? Can I do it via plugin  or is there a step-by-step code that I can use?

Comment: Do some Google research and you will find all you need to know. There is no subscription or payment for setting up Multisite. You simply edit a configuration file and WordPress changes from a default single site to a Multisite.